# Javascript: Retrieving which of a drop-down menu has been selected without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, menu, element, intervals

EDIT: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke7kdzco/)

I'm not sure how to approach this. I'm reluctant to use an unnecessary amount of ids or classes.

I have a drop-down menu that contains options for changing the speed of how fast words are displayed on a text box in real time. I've attempted to access which option is selected and the value in milliseconds through the `getTextSpeed` function.

This is used in the `runDisplay` function which takes a given set of words from input text and displays them, one word at a time, which are staggered by the amount of milliseconds given by `getTextSpeed`.

This doesn't seem to be working. `getTextSpeed` doesn't seem to return a value, so I'm guessing that `setInterval()` is running the default.

Am I doing this incorrectly? By my understanding, this should work. I am trying to retrieve the value, not the text, and the value is a number. There are no error messages in the console, just no noticeable changes when I attempt to change the speed options when running the webpage.

```
<fieldset>
          <p>Speed</p>
            <select id="speed">
                <option value="300">200 wpm</option>
                <option value="200">300 wpm</option>
                <option value="171" selected="selected">350 wpm</option>
                <option value="150">400 wpm</option>
                <option value="133">450 wpm</option>
                <option value="120">500 wpm</option>
            </select>
      </fieldset>

function getTextSpeed() {
    var speeds = document.getElementById("speed");
    return speeds.options[speed.selectedIndex].value;
}

function start() {
  var text = document.getElementById("words").value;
  var list = text.split(/\s+/);
  runDisplay(list, "display")
} 

function runDisplay(data, id) {
        var reader = document.getElementById(id);
        var index = 0;
        var textSpeed = getTextSpeed();
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        if (data.length) {
            timer = setInterval(function() {
            reader.innerHTML = data[index++];
            index = index % data.length;
          }, textSpeed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What might `#words` and `#display` be on your markup? Also, how do you trigger `start()`?

Comment: `#words` is a `textarea` box where a user can input some text. `#display` is a `div` that displays the words.

Comment: `timer` is not defined anywhere, so it will fail there, other than that I don't see any error.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have a `var` named `timer` in my js file.

Comment: Maybe I could add a JSFiddle with my code? Maybe seeing the whole picture will help?

Comment: Yes, that would help a lot. We need the exact code, no use chasing ghost code.

Comment: Alright, I'll add it to the main post and comment the link here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ke7kdzco/

Comment: Your [code works](https://jsfiddle.net/qjf7nw6f/), all I did was change the fiddle options so the JS code is wrapped on the `head` portion of the document.

Comment: Really? I don't seem to notice any differences when I change the speed.

Comment: Well, you need to click `start` again, to see the change.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I guess I need to figure out how to get it to change in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it this way?

```
function getTextSpeed() {
    var speeds = document.getElementById("speed").value;
    return speeds;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work since I don't see how it would retrieve the value of the specific option that was checked

Comment: I just tried it out; it seems as though it makes it so there is no delay at all. The retrieved delay seems to be close to 0.

Comment: try consoling the output of this ie, console.log(document.getElementById("speed").value;). What value do u get?